# How can I reduce the size of matrix?

Tags: matrices, size, blkarray

How can I reduce the size of below matrix?
(i.e. this matrix is wide, i want to reduce the distance of entries.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} %
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S}=
\begin{blockarray}{*{10}{c} l}
\begin{block}{*{10}{>{$\footnotesize}c<{$}} l}
Rose & Teal & Plum & Sand & Peach & & & & & &\\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{[*{10}{c}]>{$\footnotesize}l<{$}}
1&0 &\cdots & 0     & 1 & 0 &      &\cdots &      & 0 \bigstrut[t] & small \\
1&0 &\cdots & 0     &-1 & 0 &      &\cdots &      & 0              & medium \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 & 1 &0     &\cdots &      & 0              & large \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 &-1 &0     &\cdots &      & 0              & large \\
 &  &       &       &   &   &      &       &      &                &        \\
 &  &       &       &   &   &      &       &      &                &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 1 & 0 &\cdots&    0  &  1   & 0              &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 1 & 0 &\cdots&    0  &  -1  & 0              &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 0 & 1 & 0    &\cdots &  0   &1               &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 0 & 1 & 0    &\cdots &  0   &-1              &        \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to reduce, precisely?

Comment: Sorry about exactness. My matric is wide, I want to reduce the distance of entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't say exactly what it is that you want to be reduced and what not, I'm just guessing that you want the matrix itself to be smaller.  (I haven't changed any of your other code, just added `\footnotesize` around the matrix.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} %
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S}=
{\footnotesize
\begin{blockarray}{*{10}{c} l}
\begin{block}{*{10}{>{$\footnotesize}c<{$}} l}
Rose & Teal & Plum & Sand & Peach & & & & & &\\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{[*{10}{c}]>{$\footnotesize}l<{$}}
1&0 &\cdots & 0     & 1 & 0 &      &\cdots &      & 0 \bigstrut[t] & small \\
1&0 &\cdots & 0     &-1 & 0 &      &\cdots &      & 0              & medium \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 & 1 &0     &\cdots &      & 0              & large \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 &-1 &0     &\cdots &      & 0              & large \\
 &  &       &       &   &   &      &       &      &                &        \\
 &  &       &       &   &   &      &       &      &                &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 1 & 0 &\cdots&    0  &  1   & 0              &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 1 & 0 &\cdots&    0  &  -1  & 0              &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 0 & 1 & 0    &\cdots &  0   &1               &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 0 & 1 & 0    &\cdots &  0   &-1              &        \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry,about exactness. My matrix is very wide ,i want to reduce distance of entry.

Answer (score 4):

Same as others, I'm not sure what you really want to reduce, but my idea is you may be able to divide the big matrix into four small matrices. Along the diagonal, you have matrix `T` and upper right and bottom left corners have 4x4 all zero matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} %
\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{T}=
\begin{blockarray}{*{6}{c} l}
\begin{block}{*{6}{>{$\footnotesize}c<{$}} l}
Rose & Teal & Plum & Sand & Peach & & \\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{[*{6}{c}]>{$\footnotesize}l<{$}}
1&0 &\cdots & 0     & 1 & 0 & small  \\
1&0 &\cdots & 0     &-1\phantom{-} & 0 & medium \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 & 1 & large  \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 &-1\phantom{-} & large  \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
%
\[
\mathbf{S}=\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{T} & \textbf{0} \\
\textbf{0} & \textbf{T}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you about your answer, however i would to use elmentry row operations, and other reason I didn't write the central entry. It's not block-matrix.

Comment: @RamtinValedeinasl, how you suppose that people here would know this? Please edit your questions and add missing information (number of columns, number of rows, etc) .

Answer (score 2):

You may reduce the intercolumn space, which `blkarray` decides in a different way than for `array`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut} %
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\addtolength{\csname BA@colsep\endcsname}{-4pt}
\mathbf{S}=
\begin{blockarray}{*{10}{c} l}
\begin{block}{*{10}{>{$\footnotesize}c<{$}} l}
Rose & Teal & Plum & Sand & Peach & & & & & &\\
\end{block}
\begin{block}{[*{10}{c}]>{$\footnotesize}@{\quad}l<{$}}
1&0 &\cdots & 0     & 1 & 0 &      &\cdots &      & 0 \bigstrut[t] & small \\
1&0 &\cdots & 0     &-1 & 0 &      &\cdots &      & 0              & medium \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 & 1 &0     &\cdots &      & 0              & large \\
0&1 &0      &\cdots & 0 &-1 &0     &\cdots &      & 0              & large \\
 &  &       &       &   &   &      &       &      &                &        \\
 &  &       &       &   &   &      &       &      &                &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 1 & 0 &\cdots&    0  &  1   & 0              &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 1 & 0 &\cdots&    0  &  -1  & 0              &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 0 & 1 & 0    &\cdots &  0   &1               &        \\
0&  &\cdots &       & 0 & 1 & 0    &\cdots &  0   &-1              &        \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]